Getting "invalid ELF header" for bcrypt when I try to deploy my Node JS application to Heroku
So I'm trying to deploy my NodeJS application to Heroku. However, when I run "heroku open" my application gets an error message, and when I run "heroku logs --tail" I get this :
2024-09-20T20:50:12.740428+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: /app/server/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header
I've tried reinstalling bcrypt, removing the node_modules folder completely, and also replacing bcrypt with bcryptjs, but I still got the same error message.

r u pushing node_modules also. make sure you add it to .gitignore file

I have this in my gitignore :
dependencies
/node_modules
/.pnp
.pnp.js
